# Test failing unexpectedly

Tags: hardhat, unittesting, test, bignumber

This is code for my unit test scripts, I don't know where I am wrong.

```js
const { deployments, ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe.skip
  : describe("NFTMarketplace test", function () {
      4
      let nftMarketplaceContract, basicNftContract, nftMarketplace, basicNft
      const PRICE = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
      const TOKEN_ID = 0
      beforeEach(async function () {
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        deployer = accounts[0]
        player = accounts[1]
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        nftMarketplaceContract = await ethers.getContract("NftMarketplace")
        nftMarketplace = await nftMarketplaceContract.connect(deployer)
        basicNftContract = await ethers.getContract("BasicNft")
        basicNft = await basicNftContract.connect(deployer)
        await basicNft.mintNft()
        await basicNft.approve(nftMarketplaceContract.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
      })
      describe("ListItem", function () {
        it("Lists nft", async function () {})
      })
    })
```

**ERROR:**

```
"before each" hook for "Lists nft":
     Error: cannot override "_hex","_isBigNumber","fromTwos","toTwos","abs","add","sub","div","mul","mod","pow","and","or","xor","mask","shl","shr","eq","lt","lte","gt","gte","isNegative","isZero","toNumber","toBigInt","toString","toHexString","toJSON" (operation="overrides", overrides=["_hex","_isBigNumber","fromTwos","toTwos","abs","add","sub","div","mul","mod","pow","and","or","xor","mask","shl","shr","eq","lt","lte","gt","gte","isNegative","isZero","toNumber","toBigInt","toString","toHexString","toJSON"], code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is **approve()** from [ERC721](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-approve-address-uint256-) it only takes 2 arguments:

`approve(address to, uint256 tokenId)`

You need to remove **PRICE**

```js
await basicNft.approve(nftMarketplaceContract.address, TOKEN_ID)
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: What do your mintNft() and approve() functions look like?

Comment: `function mintNft() public {
    _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
    s_tokenCounter = s_tokenCounter + 1;
  }`
And approve is function from ERC721 contract that is imported in the contract by using **@openzeppelin/contract**

Comment: Yes, It worked! thanks